# Beginner mistake in Linq Extension Methods with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am writing my first application with Entity Framework and got lost. I followed advices from similiar threads but with no success.

I want to execute the following in my service method (just get ALL the data):

```
 using (WeatherStationDbContext entityContext = new WeatherStationDbContext())
            {
                var weatherData = entityContext.Weather
                                                .Include(x => x.Sensor)
                                                .Include(x => x.Position.Select(p => p.Location))
                                                .ToList();

(...)
```

And in .Include(x => x.Position.***Select(p => p.Location))*** I get an error:
'Position' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting...

I followed the code from for e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

```
// Load all blogs, all related posts, and all related comments 
var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                   .Include(b => b.Posts.Select(p => p.Comments)) 
                   .ToList();
```

My classes:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Width { get; set; }

    public int Length { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SensorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Sensor Sensor { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public float CoordinateX { get; set; }

    public float CoordinateY { get; set; }

}

public class Sensor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SensorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Sensor Sensor { get; set; }

    public int PositionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Position Position { get; set; }

    public float Temperature { get; set; }

    public float Humidity { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

In DbContext:

```
public DbSet<Sensor> Sensor { get; set; }
public DbSet<Location> Location { get; set; }
public DbSet<Position> Position { get; set; }
public DbSet<Weather> Weather { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Weather>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Sensor)
                .WithMany()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Weather>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Position)
                .WithMany()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

}
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [`ThenInclude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)?  The article I have linked is for EF7/"EF Core".

Comment: Do you have the appropriate foreign key relationships defined on the SQL server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your Linq to the following:

```
var weatherData = entityContext.Weather
                                .Include(x => x.Sensor)
                                .Include(x => x.Position.Location)
                                .ToList();
```

The reason you encounter the problem is that Position is not a collection. As detailed in the MSDN documentation for the [DbExtensions.Include Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx):

> **Remarks**
>
> The path expression must be composed of simple property access
>   expressions together with calls to **Select** in order to compose
>   additional includes after including a collection property. Examples of
>   possible include paths are:
>
> - To include a reference and then a reference one level down:
>     `query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference.Level2Reference)`.
> - To include a collection and then a reference one level down:       `query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference))`.

Comment: Yeesss, thank you! Could you maybe explain why I don't have to use Select() or why I can't as in the examples posted on msdn(link in my post)

Comment: @cantdoanything33 No problem, just updated my answer.